# How do I override the `**` operator used for kwargs in variadic functions for my own user-defined classes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variadic-functions

I would like to be able to unpack my own dictionary-like class.

```
class FauxDict:
    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return 99
    def __iter__(self):
        return range(0, 1)
    def to_map(self):
        return map(lambda x: True, range(0, 2))

def bar(**kwargs):
    pass

dct = {"x":1, "y":2}
bar(**dct) # no error

dct = FauxDict()
bar(**dct) # error

dct = FauxDict()
bar(**dct.to_map()) # error
```

The errors are:

```
bar(**dct) # error
TypeError: bar() argument after ** must be a mapping, not FauxDict

bar(**dct.to_map()) # error
TypeError: bar() argument after ** must be a mapping, not map
```

Also, which python class(es) technically qualify as being mappings?

Comment: `map` ≠ mapping

Comment: `**` isn't an operator you can overload; it's part of the function-call syntax.

Comment: But there is a good question here: which types (other than `dict`, if any), can be passed to a function with a `**` parameter. Or rather, what is the minimal required interface for a class to be usable in this context.

Comment: `.keys()` and `.__getitem__()` should be sufficient, possibly other combinations.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-mapping

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Implementing `.keys()` and `.__getitem__()` will be sufficient to allow an instance of your custom class to be expanded using `**`.

The relevant parts of the cpython source are in [ceval.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/ceval.c#L3534) which uses `_PyDict_MergeEx`, and thus `dict_merge` from [dictobject.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/dictobject.c#L2467-L2471) which states:

> ```
>     /* We accept for the argument either a concrete dictionary object,
>      * or an abstract "mapping" object.  For the former, we can do
>      * things quite efficiently.  For the latter, we only require that
>      * PyMapping_Keys() and PyObject_GetItem() be supported.
>      */
> ```

And indeed, implementing these two methods works as you would expect:

```
class MyMapping:
    def __init__(self, d):
        self._d = d

    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return self._d[k]

    def keys(self):
        return self._d.keys()


def foo(a, b):
    print(f"a: {a}")
    print(f"b: {b}")

mm = MyMapping({"a":"A", "b":"B"})
foo(**mm)
```

Output:

```
a: A
b: B
```

Side note: your `.keys()` implementation need only return an iterable (e.g. a list would be fine), not necessarily a `dict_keys` object like I do above for simplicity.  That line could also have been `return list(self._d.keys())` without issue.

Something unusual like the following would also work:

```
class MyMapping:
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return 2

    def keys(self):
        return ["a", "b", "c"]

def foo(a, b, **kwargs):
    print(f"a: {a}")
    print(f"b: {b}")
    print(f"kwargs: {kwargs}")

mm = MyMapping()
foo(**mm)
```

Output:

```
a: 2
b: 2
kwargs: {'c': 2}
```